# getRGB and getRaster brings different results

Tags: java, image-processing, bufferedimage

If I create an `BufferedImage` in that way:

```
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(4, 3, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    image.getRaster().setPixels(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), new int[]
                    {
                            0, 255, 192, 183,
                            83, 143, 52, 128,
                            102, 239, 34, 1
                    }
    );
```

And then when get pixels values using `getRGB` method:

```
    for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
            System.out.print((image.getRGB(x, y)) & 0xFF);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

I see result that differ from input:

```
0 255 225 220 
155 197 125 188 
170 248 102 13
```

I could get original values using `image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()`, but why `getRGB` results are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are directly writing pixels to the Raster, but you go through the Image API for getting them back.

These are very different API's, the Raster works with *raw* pixel data, while the Image API takes the ColorModel into account. When you call getRGB(), the call is delegated *through* the ColorModel, so some [nonlinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB) conversion between the sRGB color space and the Raster's color space can be/is performed.

If you try to convert them backwards:

```
    for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
            int rgb = image.getRGB(x, y);
            image.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
        }
    }
```

in `Raster` data you will see results that are very close to original:

```
0 255 192 183 
84 142 52 128 
103 239 34 1
```

So everything is correct, just assumption that 8-bit grayscale linearly converts to sRGB is wrong.

Comment: But really 8-bit gray image must fit into 32-bit ARGB without losing precision. But what should happen to `34` to become `102` after conversion? It is very strange, there must be more sane explanation... because in this case `getRGB ` seemed to be useless.

Comment: @НиколайМитропольский If you want the same values as you passed in, `getRGB` is useless (unless your input values *and* your destination image happens to be in sRGB color space already). It's not so much about "losing precision", it's just that color space conversion will change the values (from linear gray to sRGB in your case).

Comment: @НиколайМитропольский The sRGB color space is non-linear (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB). You are applying a simplified model for pixel data that is only suitable when everything is in the same color space.